# API for developers. What Content-Type should I use?

Tags: json, api, content-type

I'm developing now API for developers feature, which gives users API access to some functions of our product.

All responses are in **json** format.

HTTP **Content-Type** header in our server's response is **text/plain; charset=utf-8**

Should I send one of this:

- **application/json**
- **text/x-json**
- **text/json**

instead of text/plain.

Or for API feature text/plain Content-Type is acceptable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `application/json` as mentioned in the [official JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).

Answer (score 3):

[`application/json`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)